# Block a console app from queuing callback requests

Tags: c#, .net-core, nservicebus

Is there a way to not queue callback messages? I have two .Net Core console apps and I'm sending callbacks with NServiceBus with RabbitMQ as a transport. Everything works fine, when I press a button the sender sends a callback waits for the response.

However for some reason, if I press the button for sending a message twice, the messages somehow "queue" and I get 2 callbacks and responses in a row `(callback => response, callback => response)`. Is there a way to not queue these callbacks?

Here's some snippets:

`Sender`

```
while (true)  // Running a loop and simulating input with the console
{
  var key = Console.ReadKey();
  Console.WriteLine();

  switch (key.Key)
    {
      case ConsoleKey.D1: 

        var urMessage = new UricaRequestMessage
        {
        }

        var sendOptions = new SendOptions();
        sendOptions.SetDestination("Urica");  // The namespace where UricaRequestMessageHandler lives

        log.Info($"Sending a request to Urica");
        
        // Callback sent from here
        var response = await endpointInstance.Request<int>(urMessage, sendOptions)  
                             .ConfigureAwait(false);                           

        log.Info($"Callback recieved from Urica with response: {response}");

        break;

      case ConsoleKey.Q:
        return;
      
      default:
        log.Info("Unknown key. Please try again");
        break;
   }
}
```

`MessageHandler`

```
public Task Handle(UricaRequestMessage message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
  // Recieved a message, starting to do some things

  Thread.Sleep(2000); // Doing stuff, calculating, speculating...

  //  Returning result
  return context.reply(4);
```

Comment: I think your question is how to not process these sequentially? Messages will always be queued as that is the nature of messaging.

Comment: You don't have two messages in flight in parallel. It's the requests that are queued. The calls to `Request` and `ReadKey` will both block waiting for a result. So your first keypress is detected, the request is sent, the console app waits for a response, then it gets it, logs it, and spins back around the loop. In that time you've already pressed a key so it sends and waits again.